# Targetting a class with multiple classes on the parent

Tags: html, css

Here's the HTML,

```
<body class="home page page-id-13">
   <div class="targetthis">
   </div>
</body>
```

I want to target the class "targetthis" **only** when the body class has both "home" and "page" on it.

Comment: What CSS selector have you used to come to the fact it does not scope this particular div ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
body.home.page .targetthis
```

by removing the spaces you are saying that you want an element with both classes, and by using the body, you are saying you are wanting the body element with both classes

If you only want `targetthis` as the direct child then you need to add the `>`

[More info on multiple class / id selectors](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/)

Comment: Thanks @Pete. I wasn't aware we could go beyond one class on an element.

Answer (score 1):

Use both the classes in your target CSS selector like below.

```
 body.home.page .targetthis
 {
   background-color:red;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s1kc896x/)

Answer (score 1):

You could just write 
    firstClass.secondClass.thirdClass .childNodeClass

https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/